# Invalid PGP Signature when updating packages in MSYS2 - Despite fixes

Tags: windows, msys2, pacman

Ever since June 2020, I have been unable to update my packages with `pacman -Syu`. When I try, I get the following error:

(It gets up to "Checking package integrity", then shows errors like this for every single package)

```
error: gcc-libs: signature from "David Macek <david.macek.0@gmail.com>" is unknown trust
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/gcc-libs-10.2.0-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n]
```

Now, helpfully, MSYS2 does have a post explaining why this occurred and how to fix it: https://www.msys2.org/news/#2020-06-29-new-packagers

However, despite following all of those steps, nothing changed and I get the same errors.

For clarity, I did the following:

```
curl -O http://repo.msys2.org/msys/x86_64/msys2-keyring-r21.b39fb11-1-any.pkg.tar.xz
curl -O http://repo.msys2.org/msys/x86_64/msys2-keyring-r21.b39fb11-1-any.pkg.tar.xz.sig
pacman-key --verify msys2-keyring-r21.b39fb11-1-any.pkg.tar.xz.sig
pacman -U msys2-keyring-r21.b39fb11-1-any.pkg.tar.xz
```

Those "worked" (no errors) but didn't fix anything, so I tried:

```
rm -r /etc/pacman.d/gnupg/
pacman-key --init
pacman-key --populate msys2
```

But that didn't accomplish anything either.

What do I do?

Answer (score 15):

The original key updating procedure [News-MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/news/#2020-06-29-new-packagers) can be made to work by adding one more command:

```
$ pacman-key --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --refresh-keys
```

The packager's key as delivered in *msys2-keyring-r21.b39fb11-1-any.pkg.tar.xz* has expired, and needs to be refreshed.

```
pub   rsa4096 2018-01-14 [SC] [expired: 2021-06-19]
      87771331B3F1FF5263856A6D974C8BE49078F532
uid           [ expired] David Macek <david.macek.0@gmail.com>
```

Unfortunately, the keyserver used by older version of **pacman-key** command is not valid anymore.

```
$ pacman-key --refresh-keys
gpg: error retrieving 'alexey.pawlow@gmail.com' via WKD: No data
gpg: error reading key: No data
gpg: refreshing 1 key from hkps://hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net
gpg: keyserver refresh failed: No name
==> ERROR: Could not update key: F40D263ECA25678A
```

Keyserver value in newer pacman-key was changed to *keyserver.ubuntu.co*m by this [msys2/MSYS2-keyring](https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-keyring/commit/e8339d72671ae7f0cae5c06f88503057f0f06603) commit.  Hence, the explicit **--keyserver** option for the **pacman-key** command at the beginning of this answer.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me. From ["Nulano"](https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/issues/2058#issuecomment-947376975):

```
pacman -S msys2-keyring
```

Then use `pacman -Syu` as normal.

Tried the solutions at [Msys 2020-06-29 - new packagers](https://www.msys2.org/news/#2020-06-29-new-packagers). Didn't work for me.

Comment: A month later I had another issue with the keys, and your solution seems to have worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After trying a few other things (like disabling sourceforge mirrors) I found none worked.

Instead, I downloaded the latest tar of the project (since I cannot run the .exe) which is located at:

http://repo.msys2.org/distrib/msys2-x86_64-latest.tar.xz

Once downloaded, I went into C:/msys64/ and made a copy of the /home folder, then deleted all of the contents.

I then copied in the latest from the tar into there, and finally copied the /home folder back.

Now, MSYS2 finally works properly again. Though it does mean installing all packages over again.

Comment: I did similarly, but tried to only replace GPG-related files. I ran msys2.exe in the extracted source so that all keys are initialized/setup properly. I then copied (and overwrote) the following files to my original Msys2 installation:
/etc/pacman.d/gnupg/pubring.gpg
/etc/pacman.d/gnupg/pubring.gpg~
/etc/pacman.d/gnupg/secring.gpg
/etc/pacman.d/gnupg/tofu.db
/etc/pacman.d/gnupg/trustdb.gpg
/usr/share/pacman/keyrings/msys2-revoked
/usr/share/pacman/keyrings/msys2-trusted
Disclaimer: I have (practically) no idea what these files do, but it fixed my issue without reinstalling from scratch

Comment: That was the only solution for me too, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it on my gitlab stage by following instructions at https://www.msys2.org/docs/ci/ for Other Systems, adapted as follows:

```
# install wget
- Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/current/wget.exe" -OutFile "wget.exe"
# download and install MSYS2
- .\wget.exe -O msys2-installer.sfx.exe --no-check-certificate "https://repo.msys2.org/distrib/x86_64/msys2-base-x86_64-20230718.sfx.exe"
- .\msys2-installer.sfx.exe -y -oC:\

# Run MSYS2 for the first time and update it
- C:\msys64\usr\bin\bash -lc ' '
# Update MSYS2
- C:\msys64\usr\bin\bash -lc 'pacman --noconfirm -Syuu'  # Core update (in case any core packages are outdated)
- C:\msys64\usr\bin\bash -lc 'pacman --noconfirm -Syuu'  # Normal update
```